# One service for all the components

Tags: angular, angular-services

I am using a pattern in which storing all the data of my app in a single named `main data service`. After that i will subscribe all the component to this.The fact is here that all the components doesn't need all the data in the `main data service`.

I would like to have all the data centralised, but I am not sure this is the way to do that or not,Should I split Data into Different services.?
Will it affect my overall Performance if many components subscribe to the same `main data service`.

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You split functionality into services, not data. Data is fetched from different methods defined in service.

Having one service with too many functions is a maintenance hazard. Same file will  change for every feature change and a change in one part of application will have more chances to break another feature.

It is a good idea to break it into number of services feature wise or functionality wise, but your criteria for breaking it should remain consistent throughout development or support cycle.

Into how many files? It depends on your criteria and application design.

In angular, it will not be bad performance wise because every user running it on his own browser will execute his own instance of main data service.

It will only be that if you want to load different files for different components, loading one file will have bigger size.